# CSS drop down menu navigator using a table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a drop down menu navigator using a table, but I am having a problem. I am hiding the visibility of the tables and using hover to make it visible but it doesn't work - it is still not visible. Here is the code:

```
           table
    {
        background-color: #a9a9a9;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    a:hover
    {   
        color: #f0e68c;
    }
    a
    {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .table2
    {
        position: relative;
        left: 685;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .table2 th
    {
        border-top: 1px solid white;
    }


        .table1 th
    {
        border-left: 1px solid white;
    }

    #home:hover
    {
        background-color: black;
    }
    #register:hover
    {
        background-color: black;
    }
    #login:hover
    {
        background-color: black;
    }
    #download:hover
    {
        background-color: black;
    }
    #other:hover
    {
        background-color: black;
    }
    #other:hover .table2
    {
        visibility: visible;
    }
```

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: Best hing is not to use tables for your markup, use a list or divs

Comment: A `ul` would be your best bet for this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a tutorial on my site which shows you how to create a drop down menu using only CSS and HTML, you can also download the full code. As others have said, you should only use a table to display tabular data.

[**CSS3 Dropdown Menu Tutorial**](http://www.read-design.co.uk/css3-dropdown-menu-tutorial/)

Comment: I've already done it with list, I'm just wondering if it is possible to do that with table.

Comment: It's possible but not recommended. Most websites use to be built only using tables back 10 years plus. But DIVs and lists are much easier to style and work with.

Answer (score 2):

You really shouldn't use tables for anything but representing tabular data. 
Positioning elements using CSS without table is a little tricky, but by just reading about the box model and how the different display options work you'll figure it out.

**Box Model and positioning**

- [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/)
- [W3 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html)
- [Box Model and positioning](http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/box-model)

For navigation menus you should probably use an ul this is the standard way of doing this.

Comment: I've already done it with list, I'm just wondering if it is possible to do that with table.

Comment: Of course it's possible with some effort, but it's superior and I don't see why you would ever want to use it over the `ul` approach.

Comment: I guess I should go with the standard way (listing order), Thanks for the help dude, I appreciate it.

Comment: @user2953265 No problem, the best of luck with your project.